# Is it possible and How to establish outgoing trust relationship from resource domain without any approvals in domain with users?

Tags: windows, security, trust-relationship

There is domain U with users and domain R with resources.
I need to run IIS application on machine from domain R on behalf of concrete user from domain U (this account from U is used for NTLM authentication by external web services).

I tried following test to simulate Prod environment: created two independent root domain forests, created outgoing trust relationship from domain R to domain U,  but to achieve success I enforced to create incoming trust relationship in domain U using shared password (On test environment I have this possibility but I haven't on PROD.) Below is configuration of outgoing trust relationship I hoped will solve the problem but it didn't:

> This domain: R
>     Specified domain: U
>     Direction:
>     Outgoing: Users in the specified domain can authenticate in the local domain.
>   Trust type: External
>   Transitive: No
>   Outgoing trust authentication level: Domain-wide authentication.
>   Sides of trust: Create the trust for this domain only.

Is it possible and How to establish one way outgoing trust relationship for resources of domain R without any approvals in domain U with users? That is domain U should not be aware about such trust relationship. On test environment I have possibility to take action in AD of domain U but I havn't any credentials to establish trust on PROD. I think this should be plausible - If I trust some person to do something with my resources why should I obtain his approval. Maybe only because I create his responsibility to perform such activity.

Comment: not sure if that's possible, you'll be using different authentication realms

Comment: Add it to the domain? Or provide user separate non-domain credentials to connect with.

Comment: Adding to domain means policy will be applied - and  I don't want loose control. And this is big organization - any action in the main forest will consume a couple of weeks.  I need fast solution.

Comment: user of service should be from main forest because service invoke external services with windos authentication.